# Change font-family in ng2-nvd3 (Angular2)

Tags: css, angular, charts, fonts, ng2-nvd3

I'm trying to change the general font-family or atleast the labels used by nvd3 for Angular2 to Open Sans. Any approach using CSS hasn't worked so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you tried in CSS? It might be that you need to use a `:host /deep/` selector, or it could just be a specificity thing.

Comment: HI! I've tried changing these classes: `.nvd3 text{} .nvd3 .title{} svg text{} .nvtooltip {} .nv-x{} .nv-y{} .nv-axis{} *{}`

Comment: inline css hasn't worked either

Comment: if I had to guess, I'd say specificity. Try `!important` just to see if it will take the style at all. It would be helpful for us to see some code. Why not Plunker maybe?

Comment: @BananaJoe you have to try the not important. As, this is a closed issue on github as well https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/441